# Proving that the Lie algebra of the Lie group of a torus Lie$(\mathbb{T}^n)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

I am new to the Lie Algebra of a Lie Group and I have difficulty showing that the Lie algebra of the Lie Group of the $n$-torus $\mathbb{T}^n = \mathbb{S}^1 \times \cdots \times \mathbb{S}^1$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I know that using angle coordinates $\theta^i$ for each $i$th $\mathbb{S}^1$ factor, $\partial/ \partial \theta^i$, which is the angle coordinate vector field, forms a basis $(\partial/ \partial \theta^1, \dots , \partial/ \partial \theta^n)$ for Lie($\mathbb{T}^n)$.

But how can I show that this is abelian, i.e. for all smooth left invariant vector fields, $X$ and $Y$ on $\mathbb{T}^n$, we have $[X,Y]=0$? I know the $[\partial / \partial \theta^i, \partial/ \partial \theta^j]=0$ for all $i,j$ but how do I use this to show that $[X,Y]=[X^i \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^i},Y^i \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^i}]=(X^i \frac{\partial Y^j}{\partial \theta^i}- Y^i \frac{\partial X^j}{\partial \theta^i})\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^j}=0?$ And why is this isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: These objects that you wrote down are operators, you need to make them act on a sufficiently regular (eg. smooth) function and see what they give. By Schwartz, it will be zero.

Comment: @Bcpicao What do you mean by Schwartz?

Comment: The theorem that "mixed partial derivatives" are symmetric provided you act on a $\mathcal C^2$-function is due to H. Schwarz.

Comment: @krm2233 I suppose you mean $(X^i \frac{\partial Y^j}{\partial \theta^i}- Y^i \frac{\partial X^j}{\partial \theta^i})\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta^j}=0$ for all smooth $f$ by Schwarz? I'm not sure what theorem of Schwarz you mean here. Could you please show how this eqaulity holds from Schwarz?

Comment: Since the space of left invariant vector fields are spanned by the $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta^i}$'s (as a real vector space), one has for any $\xi\in \mathrm{Lie}(T^n)$ has $\xi=X^i\partial_{\theta^i}$ for $X^i \in \mathbb{R}$. Then for any $\xi=X^i\partial_{\theta^i}$ and $\zeta=Y^j\partial_{\theta^j}$ we have $[\xi, \zeta]=[X^i\partial_{\theta^i}, Y^j\partial_{\theta^j}]=X^iY^j[\partial_{\theta^i},\partial_{\theta^j}]=0$.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter We always have $[\partial_{x^i},\partial_{x^j}]=0$ for coordinate vector fields $\partial_{x^i}$. So doesn't your last computation imply $[\zeta, \xi]=0$ for all smooth vector fields $\xi$ and $\zeta$?

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter I'm actually very confused by this. So I think by bilinearity, we should always have $[X^i \partial_{x^i}, Y^j\partial_{x^j}]=X^i Y^j[\partial_{x^i},\partial_{x^j}]$. But $[\partial_{x^i},\partial_{x^j}]=0$ for all $i,j$ by definition since mixed partial derivatives are equal. But then this implies that for any two smooth vector fields in any smooth manifold, the Lie bracket is $0$ which should obviously be false. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: The elements of the Lie algebra of $T^n$ are (constant!) real linear combinations of the $\partial_{\theta^i}$s, so since the Lie bracket is bilinear (over $\mathbb{R}$ not $C^\infty$) my statements are valid. In general one has $[X^i\partial{x^i}, Y^j\partial_{x^j}]=X^iY^j[\partial_{x^i},\partial_{x^j}]+(X^i\partial_{x^i}Y^j-Y^i (\partial_{x^i}X^j))\partial_{x^j}=(X^i\partial_{x^i}Y^j-Y^i (\partial_{x^i}X^j))\partial_{x^j}$ as you have said above. In this case each of the $X^i$ and $Y^j$ are constant giving the desired result.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter Yes I think I just figured out what you meant here. So you mean since the differential of the left translation in $S^1$ is the identity, a left-invariant vector field in $S^1$ is constant coefficient, so the $X^i$ and $Y^j$ you stated are all constant and the Lie bracket is $0$ right? But then how do we conclude from this that the Lie algebra is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$? Is $\mathbb{R}^n$ the only $n$-dimensional abelian Lie Algebra?

Comment: That's correct. There is a natural isomorphism between $Lie(T^n)$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the trivial Lie bracket given by $\partial_{\theta^i}\mapsto e^i$. In fact there is a natural Lie algebra isomorphism between $Lie(V/\Gamma)$ and $V$ (equipped with the abelian bracket) given by mapping the constant vector fields on $V$ to the quotient.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter A left invariant vector field $X$ on $G$ means $d(L_g)_{g'}(X_{g'})=X_{gg'}$ for all $g,g'\in G$ where $L_g$ is the left translation. The differential being the identity means $d(L_g)$ is the identity. But then how does this apply to the point $g'$? Doesn't it leave the point at $g'$ so $d(L_g)_{g'}(X_{g'})=X_{g'}$? I am not clear why this means the vector field $X^i \partial{x^i}$ has coefficients $X^i$ constants. Could you please elaborate on this part for me? And why is the map $\partial_{\theta^i}\mapsto e^i$ a bijection? I am not clear what you mean by $e^i$ here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing a longer response here rather than in the comments, since it is no place for extended discussion.

If $\Gamma\subset V$ a lattice, the map $V\to V/\Gamma$ is a local diffeomorphism as the associated short exact sequence $0\to\Gamma\to V\to V/\Gamma\to 0$ induces $0\to Lie(\Gamma)\to V\to Lie(V/\Gamma)\to 0$ as a short exact sequence of Lie algebras (here we make the identification $Lie(V)\cong T_eV\cong V$) and since $\dim \Gamma=0$ the map $V\to Lie(V/\Gamma)$ is an isomorphism.

More generally if $\pi:M\to M/G$ where $G$ is a discrete group acting via a covering space action we have an identification $T_q\pi:T_qM\to T_p(M/G)$ for $q\in \pi^{-1}(p)$. Changing between identifications is done by precomposing by $T_{\phi_g^{-1}q}\phi_g$. We can actually think of vector fields on $M/G$ as vector fields on $M$ which are invartiant with respect to $G$, i.e. $\phi_{g*}X=X$.

We can then think of a vector field on $V/\Gamma$ as a vector field on $V$ which is invariant under the $\Gamma$ action. In particular a vector field $X$ on $V$ defines a vector field on $V/\Gamma$ if $X(v+\gamma)=d\phi_{\gamma}(v)X(v)$ and since the differential $d\phi_{\gamma}(v)=id: V\to V$ (remember that $T_vV\cong V$ canonically so the derivative $d\phi_{\gamma}$ is just $T_v\phi_{\gamma}$) we have $X(v+\gamma)=X(v)$ for all $\gamma\in \Gamma$. This means we can identify $\mathfrak{X}(V/\Gamma)$ with $\Gamma$ invariant smooth functions $V\to V$. Now for such a vector field to be left invariant it must have $X(v+u)=X(v)$ for all $u\in V$ since the $V/\Gamma$ action on $\mathfrak{X}(V/\Gamma)$ descends from the action of $V$ on $\mathfrak{X}(V)$, that is, the following diagram commutes
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathfrak{X}(V)^\Gamma @>{\Psi}>> \mathfrak{X}(V/\Gamma)\\
@V{\phi_{\gamma*}}VV @VV{\phi_{[\gamma]*}}V\\
\mathfrak{X}(V)^\gamma @>{\Psi}>>\mathfrak{X}(V/\Gamma)
\end{CD}
Where $\Psi$ is the map which identifies vector fields on $V/\Gamma$ with $\Gamma$ invariant vector fields on $V$. Of course if $X(v+u)=X(v)$ for all $u\in V$ then $X$ is actually constant and an element of $Lie(V/\Gamma)$ is just an element in $V$.

Per my discussion in my last comment, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector space with basis elements denoted by $e^1=(1,0, \cdots,0), e^2=(0,1,\cdots,0)$ and so on, so the map I described $\partial_{\theta^i}\mapsto e^i$ is just the map which takes the ith basis vector of $Lie(T^n)$ to the ith basis vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thank you so if the differential is the identity then the left invariant vector fields are just constant vector fields.

Comment: That's correct!